# How do I Remove the Enclosing Single Quotes from a String?

Tags: php

I have an email address enclosed in **single** quotes:

```
$email = "'test@email.com'";
```

I want to remove the single quotes to obtain:

```
$email = "test@email.com";
```

I think `test@email.com` itself may also contain single quotes if I am not wrong. Is there a neat solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove the enclosing single quotes:

```
$email = trim($email, "'");
```

Comment: I didn't know `trim` can remove quotes other than white spaces. Learnt something new today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove surrounding quotes if present:

```
$email = trim($email, "'");
```